# Testing Google Earth browser plugin with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to test an application with a web page that has the Google Earth plugin on it. I need to perform some automated testing on the Google Earth plugin. I am trying to click and move the map around using Selenium IDE. However, my clicks are not getting registered to the Earth plugin. I read somewhere that its not possible as the plugin elements are not part of the DOM.

Let me know if anybody has been able to control the Earth plugin automatically with Selenium IDE or if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: IDE won't be up to this task, try with Selenium 2

Comment: Depending on your requirements I am sure you could automate some testing in the Api. It is possible to script it to move randomly around as if being clicked and dragged. Any callback functions you would pass to events could also be triggered. What are you trying to test and why?

Comment: I am using the GEarthExtensions ([link](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/)) lib to do custom stuff outside the plugin when a user adds a placemark. The GEarthExtensions lib listens to a mousedown event to add a placemark. There currently doesn't seem to be any way to fire the mousedown event(note that this is the Google Earth event and **not a DOM event**). I could call the mousedown event handler directly but its a nested function in the GEarthExtensions lib. I could extract it out but will have to do it for all of the other handlers that I will be testing(too many changes).